# Using window.confirm instead of onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, onbeforeunload

Instead of using the `onbeforeunload` event, is there a way I can listen for when a user tries to refresh the window or close the window, and interrupt that process with my own custom `window.confirm` message? It seems that `onbeforeunload` custom messages are no longer supported across browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

true that support for `onbeforeunload` is fading.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

some browsers ignore the string passed in, and some ignore calls to `window.alert()`, `window.confirm()` and `window.prompt()`.

Many sites get around this by detecting an event that precedes window closure, such as `mouseout` before the user closes a tab.

Though it's popular these days, it feels slimy, imo. and it can be triggered when the use is doing another action (perhaps one you want, like "bookmark this page"). Often I see an html5 modal used, which is less offensive than a truly blocking confirm box. It still disrupts reading.